# Add menu class in Drupal8

Tags: drupal-8

I installed Link attribute module to add classes in menu items but its not showing attributes for already added menus i.e. the menus which are coming by default in Drupal8 menus.

How to add class in Drupal default menus i.e My account, Login and Logout menus.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the template for the menus into your theme and add classes that way?

You can find the nav templates here `core/themes/classy/templates/navigation` the one for the logged in user is `links.html.twig`. If you enable twig debug you will be able to see which templates are being used there's a guide on how to do that [here](https://sqndr.github.io/d8-theming-guide/twig/twig-debug.html). Then all you have to do is copy that template to your theme and modify it to how you want it. Example below:-

```
{% if links -%}
  {%- if heading -%}
    {%- if heading.level -%}
      <{{ heading.level }}{{ heading.attributes }}>{{ heading.text }}</{{ heading.level }}>
    {%- else -%}
      <h2{{ heading.attributes }}>{{ heading.text }}</h2>
    {%- endif -%}
  {%- endif -%}
  <ul{{ attributes.addClass('my-class') }}>
    {%- for item in links -%}
      <li{{ item.attributes }}>
        {%- if item.link -%}
          {{ item.link }}
        {%- elseif item.text_attributes -%}
          <span{{ item.text_attributes }}>{{ item.text }}</span>
        {%- else -%}
          {{ item.text }}
        {%- endif -%}
      </li>
    {%- endfor -%}
  </ul>
{%- endif %}
```

Comment: This soluion is fine.... But I also want UI interface where I can change class later on..

Comment: It can be done but not without custom code, what's the reason you'd like to change the class on the fly? Might be able to come up with another solution.

Comment: I just want that if any person wants to change the class directly then no need to go to code.. Like if I'll give this work to designer then he will not be able to find the code..

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who doesn't want to edit the twig template, a more user friendly solution is to install the [Mix](https://www.drupal.org/project/mix) module, then set id/class/target attributes from the menu link edit UI for both **custom menu links** and **pre-defined menu links**.

[image]
[image]